# How to fix 'Java build failed' in Eclipse after converting selenium IDE script?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I recorded a script using Selenium IDE and exported it in Java. Now when I want to run it on webDriver, a pop-up box is displayed-

[image]

when I select an option and click on ok "Build failed" message is displayed.
I do not have any idea how to resolve this as I am a beginner in selenium.

Comment: The title of this post is misleading. The problem you're talking about is how to run a script, not how to perform a script conversion.

Comment: Made a title that reflects the contents better

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you need to get the [junit.jar](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install) and add it to your build path (if you exported using the junit option). To add it to the buildpath:

1. Create a 'lib' folder in your project
2. Copy the .jar file into the lib folder
3. Right-click the .jar and select "Add to Build Path"

You should then be able to run as a JUnit test.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for how to run a WebDriver Java script in [E̲c̲l̲i̲p̲s̲e̲ ̲N̲e̲o̲n̲.̲3](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/neon3) that's exported from a [S̲e̲l̲e̲n̲i̲u̲m̲ ̲I̲D̲E̲ ̲2̲.̲9̲.̲1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) test case is provided below. This approach covers all 3 options for creating such a script from a test case with this Selenium IDE version; the 3 choices are as follows:

***Option 1***: Java / JUnit 4 / WebDriver

***Option 2***: Java / TestNG / WebDriver

***Option 3***: Java / JUnit 4 / WebDriver Backed

[image]

Here's the solution:
1. Ensure you have [F̲i̲r̲e̲f̲o̲x̲ ̲4̲7̲.̲0̲.̲1](http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/68836/) installed on your machine.
2. In Eclipse:

a. Under ***File***, select ***New*** **>** ***Java Project***.

[image]

b. Enter a project name in the ***Project name:*** text box, then click the ***Next >*** button.

[image]

c. Click the ***Libraries*** tab.

[image]

d. Add the following to the build path of your project:
-Each JAR that's in [t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲f̲i̲l̲e̲](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-java-2.53.1.zip)
-[T̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲f̲i̲l̲e̲](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar) (if ***Option 3*** was used)

To add JARs to this path, click the ***Add External JARs...*** button, then (in the ***JAR Selection*** window that pops up as a result) select the JARs and click the ***Open*** button.

[image]

[image]

e. Click the ***Finish*** button.

[image]

You're now done creating a Java project.

f. Expand the Java project by clicking the plus symbol that's beside it in the ***Package Explorer*** pane (in this pane, every entry with a plus sign next to it can be expanded through that sign being clicked).

[image]

g. Right click the ***src*** folder that appears below the project, then select ***New*** **>** ***Package***.

[image]

h. Enter a package name in the ***Name:*** text box, then click the ***Finish*** button.

[image]

You're now done creating a package that's in the ***src*** folder.

i. In the ***Package Explorer*** pane, right click the package you just created. Select ***New*** **>** ***Class***.

[image]

j. In the ***Name:*** text box, enter the name (excluding the .java extension) of the .java file that was created as a result of exporting the Selenium IDE test case in question, then click the ***Finish*** button.

[image]

You're now done creating a class that's in the package.

k. Copy all the lines (except for the first two) of the aforementioned .java file that was generated with Selenium IDE. Paste them over lines 3-6 of the class file you finished creating during Step j (let's call this file ***x***).

l. Save ***x***.

m. If ***Option 2*** was used and TestNG is not installed in Eclipse, carry out the following instructions:

-Select ***Help*** **>** ***Install New Software...***

[image]

-In the resulting ***Install*** window, click the ***Add...*** button.

[image]

-In the ***Add Repository*** window that pops up, enter a name in the ***Name:*** text box and ***http://beust.com/eclipse/*** in the ***Location:*** text box, then click the ***OK*** button.

[image]

-In the ***Install*** window, check the ***TestNG*** checkbox in the list of available software then click ***Next >*** twice.

[image]

[image]

-Select ***I accept the terms of the license agreement*** then click the ***Finish*** button.

[image]

(TestNG will now be installed)

-In case you get a security warning, click the ***OK*** button.

[image]

-Once the installation is complete, click ***Yes*** in the ***Software Updates*** window.

[image]

(Eclipse will now restart)

n. To run the WebDriver script, right click ***x*** in the ***Package Explorer*** pane, then hover over ***Run As***, then click:

-***JUnit Test*** for ***Options 1*** and ***3***

[image]

-***TestNG Test*** for ***Option 2***

[image]